# Packing and unpacking of arrays with Map/Table

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, memory, packed-arrays

How can I create function, that will not unpack packed arrays with Map/Table. For example I want read bytes from opened stream (this is my original goal):

```
getBytesFromStream[stream_, pos_, len_, converter_] := 
Module[{bytes}, 
    SetStreamPosition[stream, pos]; 
    bytes = BinaryReadList[stream, "Byte", len]; 
    converter[bytes]
]

bytes = 
Module[{stream = OpenRead["test.dat", BinaryFormat -> True], bytes}, 
    bytes = getBytesFromStream[stream, 0, 128, #&];
    Close[stream];
    bytes
];

bytesList = 
Module[{stream = OpenRead["test.dat", BinaryFormat -> True], bytes}, 
    bytes = Table[getBytesFromStream[stream, i, 128, #&], {i, 0, 127, 128}];
    Close[stream];
    bytes
];

Developer`PackedArrayQ[bytes]
Developer`PackedArrayQ[bytesList]
```

> True
>   False

**Table** did unpack array that was be read. 
I can pack it again. But if I have only 1Gb free memory and if I want to read file that has size about 400~500Mb - Mathematica can not process this. 
Unpacked 512Mb in the Mathematica memory has size about 1536Mb. Therefore, I want the function to return the packed result.

Comment: Do you have a (cooked-down!) example file by chance? It will be easier and less error prone to deal with real data sets.

Comment: There are no mistakes here. In the file just zeros. I'm wondering why the function **Table** (and **Map** /..) unpacks the list, which is originally packed.

Comment: Ah. So would make a better post by just ranting about ``Table[ConstantArray[0., 3], {10}] // Developer`PackedArrayQ`` and
``Identity /@ ConstantArray[0., {10, 3}] // Developer`PackedArrayQ``. This stream business is actually not related to the question. Agreed, this is a very annoying issue.

Comment: Do you know in advance what size the final array will be? In that case, preallocating (e.g. with `ConstantArray`) and _writing_ into it should resolve the issue. If not, loading smaller chucks into preallocated arrays as `Join`ing them afterwards should also work fine.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher you are right! I can create ConstantArray before reading from the file. I know file size previously!

Comment: Have you considered `ReadByteArray["test.dat"]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I follow your example, and Henrik's comment, I think there is a misunderstanding here.  [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) does not unpack; the elements themselves remain packed arrays:

```
tab = Table[ConstantArray[0., 3], {10}];

Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ tab
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True, True}
> ```

Note that packing this outer level saves very little space:

```
tab2 = Developer`ToPackedArray[tab];

ByteCount[tab]
ByteCount[tab2]
```

> ```
> 41600
>
> 41080
> ```

Note also that for large table, specifically exceeding the size given in `SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "TableCompileLength"]` the outer level *is* packed:

```
 Table[ConstantArray[0., 5], {250}] // Developer`PackedArrayQ
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Likewise `Map` does not fully unpack the array, or a command like `` Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ tab `` would return {False, False, ...}.

---

### Update and clarification

Michael E2 pointed out in a comment that `Table` only returns a packed array if the iterated expression can be compiled.  This is important and I was remiss to ignore it, especially as it relates to your question.  Indeed standard definitions such as `f[x_] := . . .` are not compiled and `Table` does not return an externally packed array.  (If the elements returned by such a function are packed they are not unpacked, as explained above.)

```
f[_] := ConstantArray[0., 5]

tab3 = Table[f[i], {i, 250}];

tab3 // Developer`PackedArrayQ

And @@ Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ tab3
```

> ```
> False
>
> True
> ```

In this specifically chosen example where the number of elements (250) is much larger than the size of each element the size difference between this output and a fully packed array is significant:

```
tab3 // ByteCount

tab3 // Developer`ToPackedArray // ByteCount
```

> ```
> 38056
>
> 10360
> ```

If this is representative of your application you may wish to operate on the data in blocks, packing each block as you go; something like this:

```
tab4 =
  Join @@ Table[
    Developer`ToPackedArray @ 
      Table[f[i + 50 j], {i, 50}],
    {j, 0, 4}
  ];

tab4 // Developer`PackedArrayQ

tab4 // ByteCount
```

> ```
> True
>
> 10360
> ```

Comment: Note that the output of `Table[]` being packed depends on the expression being compilable. (In the OP's case, I think it's not compilable, but it's not easy to test it.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Please see my update and tell me if I have adequately addressed this.

Comment: Yes, I believe it does address it as well as can be.  I suggested `ReadByteArray` in a comment above, which I think has the potential to be a better solution in the OP's actual use-case.  However, there's not enough information (esp. about the OP's function `converter[]`), nor do I have enough experience with `ByteArray` objects, to make a confident recommendation.